# В какой компонент загрузить gif анимацию?

Tags: delphi

У меня есть анимация(***.gif). мне её нужно загрузить на форму, но обычный TImage тут не подходит, поэтому вопрос как быть? Переконвертировать из gif в avi не вариант

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна анимация, то используй компонент **TAnimate** c панели **Win32**.

По его названию уже понятно его предназначение. Им пользоваться просто.

На счет загрузки *.gif в Delphi - это не возможно, по крайней мере,

используя стандартный набор компонентов.

Comment: это я  и так знаю, мне нужны как раз не стандартные компоненты

Comment: Ну тогда посмотрите это - http://delphidevelop.ru/publ/12-1-0-236

Answer (score 0):

Вместо GIF анимации можно использовать PNG анимацию (загружать только динамически!).
Правда это недоступно в Delphi 7  (в 2007 всё работает).